# Where is a tutorial for using XML with Delphi?

Tags: xml, delphi

I need a sample or tutorial on working with XML files. I want to create a file that contains a "record" to a person, something like this:

```
Name: Just Me
Age: 99
EMail: me@some.net
```

I want to learn how to read and write an XML file.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263419/getting-started-with-xml-and-delphi

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at Jeroen Pluimers Sessions at [CodeRage 4](http://conferences.embarcadero.com/coderage/sessions)

called **[Practical XML in Delphi](http://cc.embarcadero.com/download.aspx?id=27272)**

> "Starting with the XML basics, learn
>   about well formed and valid documents,
>   encoding, and recoding and XSD
>   validation. See examples in Delphi for
>   Win32 and Delphi Prism showing you
>   which tool to choose when. Finally,
>   learn where things can go wrong and
>   how to prevent that: improper but well
>   formed XML, copying data between XML
>   documents, convert XML to tables and
>   objects, etc."

Answer (score 9):

See [Creating, Parsing and Manipulating XML Documents with Delphi](http://delphi.about.com/od/windowsshellapi/a/xml_delphi.htm)

Answer (score 3):

This can get you up to speed in less than 10 minutes: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4D78MG4CaAI (a tutorial on using XML data binding wizard)

Comment: Cool, someone has watched my video.  I'm currently producing a commercial video on TXMLDocument (hopefully the first in a series on XML in Delphi).  Also http://youtu.be/7b8jbuu-RAY might be of interest

Comment: @Alister you need to do more cardiac exercise, you breath as you can barely move. its very dis-focusing in your videos, i keep thinking you are about to die, and side track from your speech.

Answer (score 3):

Wow, I just noticed this post after posting a [tutorial of Xml serialization](http://robstechcorner.blogspot.com/2009/10/xml-serialization-basic-usage.html) with Delphi 2010.

It can be looked at to see out TXmlDocument works, but there are many other methods that will work as well.

I typically use msXml unit directly as it exposes XPath which TXmlDocument does not.

Answer (score 3):

I use this VCL component:

[NativeXML](http://www.simdesign.nl/xml.html)

**Edit:**

NativeXml is currently open-sourced.