# omni xml create xml

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, omnixml

What is the fastest way to implement a creation of xml file in this format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Unicode" standalone="yes"?>
<A V1="string" V2=String >
  <B>
    <C V3="1" V4="1" V5="0"/>
  </B>
  <C V6="14.25" V7="0.2"/>
  <D>
    <E V8="1" V9="1" V10="2">
    </E>
    <E V8="2" V9="1" V10="2">
       <F V11="a" V12="B">
         <G>0</G>
       </F>
    </E>
    <E V8="1" V9="1" V10="2">
    </E>
    <E V8="2" V9="1" V10="2">
      <F V11="a" V12="B">
        <G>0</G>
      </F>
    </E>
  </D>
</A>
```

There are a lot of e, where I can generate in iterations.

However I can't seem to grasp the best approach with Omni.

Creating 10 to 20 objects for so much constant seems a mess and too much.

And could you also mention how to set the encoding to generate the file?

Comment: Are you really bound to OmniXML or do you need just a quick way to generate some XML (not necessarily with OmniXML)?

Comment: Because if not you could get some ideas here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263419/getting-started-with-xml-and-delphi

Comment: For starters, this is not a valid XML. <A> node is not terminated and there's a </sheetData> without <sheetData>.

Comment: This is an unanswerable question, because you posted made-up XML that isn't valid. (Actually, an acceptable answer would be "Highlight the XML in your question and press Ctrl+C. Switch to Notepad and press Ctrl+V. Click File->Save As... and enter YourFileName.xml. Click Save." - that's the fastest way. Please edit and provide the **real** output you're looking to obtain. Posting fake code or markup leads to mistakes (like in this question) and hides the real problems or requirements. @gabr, There's also an unterminated `<D>` and there's a `</worksheet>` without `<worksheet>`

Comment: @gabr, probably the sheetData is replaced with D and workSheet with A. (at least its fixed now).

Comment: XML is still not well-formed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
uses
  OmniXML,
  OmniXMLUtils;

procedure GetEAttr(var v8, v9, v10: integer);
begin
  v8 := Random(10);
  v9 := Random(10);
  v10 := Random(10);
end;

procedure TForm54.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  i     : integer;
  node1 : IXMLNode;
  node2 : IXMLNode;
  root  : IXMLNode;
  v10   : integer;
  v8    : integer;
  v9    : integer;
  xmlDoc: IXMLDocument;
begin
  xmlDoc := CreateXMLDoc;
  xmlDoc.AppendChild(xmlDoc.CreateProcessingInstruction('xml', 'version="1.0" encoding="Unicode" standalone="yes"'));
  root := AppendNode(xmlDoc, 'A');
  SetNodeAttr(root, 'V1', 'string');
  SetNodeAttr(root, 'V2', 'string');
  node1 := AppendNode(root, 'B');
  node2 := AppendNode(node1, 'C');
  SetNodeAttr(node2, 'V3', '1');
  SetNodeAttr(node2, 'V4', '1');
  SetNodeAttr(node2, 'V5', '0');
  node1 := AppendNode(root, 'C');
  SetNodeAttr(node1, 'V6', '14.25');
  SetNodeAttr(node1, 'V7', '0.2');
  node1 := AppendNode(root, 'D');
  for i := 1 to 4 do begin
    GetEAttr(v8, v9, v10);
    node2 := AppendNode(node1, 'E');
    SetNodeAttrInt(node2, 'V8', v8);
    SetNodeAttrInt(node2, 'V9', v9);
    SetNodeAttrInt(node2, 'V10', v10);
  end;
  XMLSaveToFile(xmlDoc, 'test.xml', ofIndent);
end;
```

Comment: SetTextChild(node_g, '0'); or SetNodeText(parent_of_g, 'g', '0');