# Builder C++ How to populate DBGrid with xml file

Tags: c++, xml, delphi, c++builder, dbgrid

I have in my application Builder C++(embarcadero) a dbgrid.. I would like to populate with data from XML file..

before to populate a dbgrid, we should convert the xml file to xml datapacket. To do that, you must define the relationship between the metadata in a data packet and the nodes of the corresponding XML document. A description of this relationship is stored in a special XML document called a transformation. In this step we can use Mapper tool to create a transformation.

In my case i have a xml file

```
    <result name="response" numFound="3098" start="0">
    <doc>
        <str name="Document Extension">PST</str>
        <str name="Document Page Count">1</str>
        <str name="DocID">1</str>
        <str name="lastModifiedIdx">2015-02-02 09:40:29.0</str>
    </doc>
    <doc>
        <str name="Document Extension">PST</str>
        <str name="Document Page Count">1</str>
        <str name="DocID">2</str>
        <str name="lastModifiedIdx">2015-02-02 09:39:53.0</str>
    </doc>
    </result>
```

with this structure(element str with attribute name), i can to load correctly in my Mapper tool to create a xstr file..

I would like to transform this file to some structure

```
   <doc>
        <Document Extension>PST</Document Extension>
        <Document Page Count>1</Document Page Count>
        <DocID>2</DocID>
        <lastModifiedIdx>2015-02-02 09:39:53.0</lastModifiedIdx>
    </doc>
```

see this link for more information : http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Converting_XML_Documents_into_Data_Packets

Any idea?

Comment: I am not sure which question you are asking - do you wish to populate a grid, or do you wish to transform some xml?

Comment: i need to populate a dbgrid with xml file... "the only way can i see is to transform xml to xml datapacket."

Comment: The link you supplied tells you exactly how to do this, in the sections with the heading *Obtaining the resulting data packet* and *Converting user-defined nodes*. What part of that is unclear to you? Once you've provided the transformation, you simply assign the appropriate properties to a `TClientDataSet` (as shown in the example), and then attach a `TDataSource` to that `TClientDataSet`, and assign that `TDataSource` to the `TDBGrid.DataSource` property. Set the `TClientDataSet.Active` property to true (or use `TClientDataSet->Open;`).

Comment: all steps(client dataset and datasource) is after then you create a xtr file with the mapper tool.. but when we need to use Mapper, we should have a structure and element without attribute to create xtr file(the transformation).. i need to transfom my xml (first src) to my xml (second code)..

Comment: As Ken said - the instructions are available in the link you provided.  You are quite right that the business of connecting a ClientDataSet to a grid comes later.  So what is the difficulty with the transformation step?

Comment: but - as an aside - a transform is not the ONLY way to solve this problem; you could parse the original xml and populate a ClientDataset directly.

Comment: i need to transfom my xml (first src) to my xml (second code).. in this case i can use mapper to generate xstr file to load on xmltransform...
@HughJones how to populate ClientDataset directly?

Comment: i) Create a clientdataset with the fields you require ii) Open the xml iii) `insert` each record into the ClientDataset

Comment: i) the field is variable element in <doc> ... how t do that?!

Comment: @HughJones you dont understant the situation.. i have a field element variable ..

Comment: I do understand - I have done this type of thing many times.  You can easily create a ClientDataset with the fields `id, extension, pages, lastmodified`.  (Read the articles by Carey Jensen on how to create clientdatasets).  To parse your xml file read some of the sources from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263419/libraries-and-tutorials-for-xml-in-delphi.

Comment: Aha! - I think I see what your confusion is - 'name' is an `attribute` of the str elements but 'PST', '1' etc are the `text` of the str elements